# How to create a Random Scenario in Scala for a Gatling Simulation

Tags: scala, performance, rest, testing, scala-gatling

I use the script below to test my server with various clients.

```
package test

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Lasttest_ThinClient extends Simulation {

 val httpProtocol = http
.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
.acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
.doNotTrackHeader("1")
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
.userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")

val scn = scenario("Lasttest: Thin Client (X Clients)")
.exec(
  http("UC-0")
    .get("/movingAverage/50/abbn")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-1")
    .get("/getBestValue")
    .queryParam("min", "2")
    .queryParam("max", "250")
    .queryParam("name", "abbn")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-2")
    .get("/getBestValueOneYear")
    .queryParam("min", "2")
    .queryParam("max", "250")
    .queryParam("name", "abbn")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-3")
    .get("/bestSimpleAveragePortfolio")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-5")
    .get("/buyHoldPortfolio")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-6")
    .get("/getBestStrategy")
)
.pause(1,3)
.exec(
  http("UC-7")
    .get("/getBestStrategyOneYear")
)

  setUp(
scn.inject(
atOnceUsers(3),
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
)
}
```

Is there a possibility to randomize the way the use cases get runned. so that every client picks per example 3 out of the 7 use cases randomly. would be nice to create a Practice-oriented scenario instead of simply executing all use cases in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools you can use to introduce randomness in your Gatling tests, eg:

- [random feeders](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/#strategies)
- [`randomSwitch`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#randomswitch)
- [random checks](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#findrandom) to capture random data

`randomSwitch` is probably what you want to use here.